# Having problem with PROJ string for custom Coordinate System

Tags: postgis, coordinate-system, proj, utm

I was looking for an exhaustive reference on instructions supported by PROJ string, but couldn't find anything yet. Only [this page](https://proj.org/usage/projections.html) in PROJ library docs - I guess that's all there is.

I have quite a straightforward goal in mind - convert certain lat/lng to specific UTM (lets say `ESPG:32618` or `+proj=utm +zone=18 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs`) and then offset easting and northing by a certain amount. But I want destination to be an actual custom coordinate system. So how do I derive it from that UTM CRS, given above mentioned operations? Should be something trivial, right? How do I do that?

I tried to set false easting and false northing, like this:

`+proj=utm +zone=18 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +x_0=-5000 +y_0=-5000 +no_defs`

But doesn't seem to have any effect in PostGIS and continues to ST_Transform to mere UTM 18N.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the [Universal Transverse Mercator](https://proj.org/operations/projections/utm.html) system, most of the parameters are implied and fixed. `utm` does not have a `x_0` parameter, so the PROJ library ignores it.

You have to use the more generic [Transverse Mercator](https://proj.org/operations/projections/tmerc.html) projection, write out all the implied parameters, and then change those:

```
+proj=tmerc +datum=WGS84 +lon_0=-75 +k_0=0.9996 +x_0=500000 +y_0=0
```

Comment: Where do I take those implied params from? Can I see somehow what params are used to generate this or that UTM zone PROJ string?

Comment: Aw... wait, they are written in that table. Is it really just that easy? Huh.

Comment: In general, you can look up the parameters in the projection's [WKT](https://epsg.io/32618#s_html_code).